# Не работает phpthumbof

Tags: modx, migx, phpthumb

Почему у меня при выводе [[+img:phpthumbof=`w=300&h=300&zc=1`]] выдает unknown
Вывожу поля через migx, без фильтра все окей, добавляю фильтр ":phpthumbof=`w=300&h=300&zc=1" перестает работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я использовал вывод здесь

> [[getImageList? &tvname=`object-gallery-photo` &tpl=`@CODE: <li><img
>   src=" [[+img:phpthumbof=w=300&h=300&zc=1]"></li>`   &docid=`[[*id]]`
>   &limit=`10` ]]

А создав чанк и уже там применив фильтр все получилось. Видимо в phpThumbOf нет возможности использовать в данном виде.